# Comments pagination on author page

Tags: comments, pagination, author

I have small problem, I have author page (`example.com/author/joe`) on this page **I have listed all author comments with pagination** but pagination doesn't work after click url is - example.com/author/joe/page/2 and page is redirect to index.php.

In other loops it works, just have problem with author page.

Any ideas ?

CODE:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$number = get_option('comments_per_page');
$offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $number;

$count = count( get_comments( array(
    'user_id' => $user_ID,
    'status' => 'approve',
) ) );

$max_total = ceil($count/$number);

$args = array(
    'user_id' => $user_ID,
    'number' => $number,
    'status' => 'approve',
    'offset' => $offset,
    'paged' => $paged
    );

$the_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $the_query->query( $args );

foreach($comments as $comment){ 
 //code
}


//Pagination
$big = 999999999;

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $max_total,
    'prev_next'=> true,
) );
```

Comment: Post code of yours.

Comment: Code added. Matt

Comment: Any ideas, what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set the `paged` parameter in your query, below is shown how to do that.

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 3,
     'paged' => $paged
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

For more information about pagination have a look at [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).